# Trying to use Thread to loop inside a Service to handle home button

Tags: android, multithreading, service, handler, sharedpreferences

I'm trying to loop inside a handler to every 2 seconds to simulate the home button press using a sharedpreference flag isHomeActive. It will try to check for the flag every 2 seconds inside the service whether it is active. If the value is no, it will try to relaunch the application but if it is yes, the application won't be relaunched. I am unable to get the loop working so far

onResume and onPause for main activity:

```
  @Override
  public void onPause()
  {
      super.onPause();
      SharedPreferences home = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(PhysicalTheftDialog.this);
      Editor edit=home.edit();
      edit.putString("isHomeActive", "no");
      edit.commit();      

  }

  @Override
  public void onResume()
  {
      super.onResume();
      SharedPreferences home = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(PhysicalTheftDialog.this);
      Editor edit=home.edit();
      edit.putString("isHomeActive", "yes");
      edit.commit();      
  }
```

The loop inside service class:

```
        SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(PhysicalTheftService.this);
    final String isHomeActive = sp.getString("isHomeActive", "");


    Runnable myRunnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
             while (isHomeActive.equals("no")) {
                  try {
                          Intent physicaldialog = new Intent(PhysicalTheftService.this, PhysicalTheftDialog.class);
                          physicaldialog.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                          PhysicalTheftService.this.startActivity(physicaldialog);
                      Thread.sleep(2000);

                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } 

             }
        }
   };
```

Comment: How are you starting your runnable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are only ever populating `isHomeActive` one time, so the value will never change. You need to populate it inside the loop.